# Adding asp.net server side controls through javascript dynamically

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to add asp.net server side control dynamically on the webpage without causing **postback**. Like can I add a calender control dynamically on a button click and handle calender events to do some other work....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that without posting back to the server. However, postbacks don't have to be intrusive: for instance, you might use an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) control to perform a partial postback that only updates the panel's contents.

See also the [DynamicPopulate](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/DynamicPopulate/DynamicPopulate.aspx) extender provided by the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Default.aspx), a good implementation of what you want to achieve.